# Model IoT data in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have to create a logical, and physical, model for MongoDB.
The challenge here is to create the smarter stucture of the mongo documents in order to speed up the queries that I have to implement.

The raw data contains the readings of an array of wheather sensors. The .csv file I have contains 22 millions of these readings.
Each reading has these fields: date, time, temperature, umidity, pressure, wind, wind_direction, rain, station_id.

The queries are the following:

Q1: Assigned a month of a year and the id of a station, find the average, minimum and maximum temperature value on days with precipitation > 0.

Q2: Find the id of the station that recorded the minimum temperature value in an assigned period.

Q3: Find the pairs of stations (id1,id2) that recorded the same temperature on some day, apportioning not only the id pair but also the day on which this occurred.

Based on these query my idea is to store the data grouping it by station and by start_date, end_date period.
Something like this:

```
   {
      "_id": 1,
      "station_id": 12345,
      "start_date": ISODate("2019-01-01T10:00:00.000Z"),
      "end_date": ISODate("2019-01-31T23:59:59.000Z"),
      "measurements": [
        {
          "date": ,
          "time": ,
          "temperature": ,
          "pressure": ...
        },
        ...
        {
          "date": ,
          "time": ,
          "temperature": ,
          "pressure": ...
        }
      ]
    }
```

I think that this structure would help me dealing quite effectively with the query Q1 and Q2, but I think that I will have problems with the query Q3.
Do you have an idea of a structure that could help me query the system effectively with the query Q3?

Thank you

Comment: The model may not work if you have a lot of `measurements` entries. MongoDB is subjected to [16MB single document size limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size)

Comment: So, I’m forced to reduce the time span in order to reduce the size of the measurements.

Comment: I would suggest that each readings / measurements to be stored as an individual document. Just keep all the fields you obtained from csv. You can leverage aggregation pipeline to achieve your 3 queries